# Bind ViewModel to MainPage.xaml

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I've got the following code in my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private IsolatedStorageSettings userLogin = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        private UserDataContract currentUser;
        private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // If an error occurs during navigation, show an error window
        private void ContentFrameNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow(e.Uri);
            errorWin.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("#/Fields/Edit", UriKind.Relative));
        }

    }
```

Now I would like to bind my ViewModel to the MainPage.xaml, how can I do this?

```
            mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = loginViewModel;
```

Doesn't really work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = mainViewModel ;
    }
```